# What's the difference between evasion and avoidance?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I know there are some technical cases where they are different, but it seems that in most common situations, relating to physical activity, they mean the same thing. For example:

> He threw the ball at me, but I avoided it
>
> He threw the ball at me, but I evaded it

Is there a difference? Or are they purely synonyms?

Comment: Could you share what you've researched in dictionaries and perhaps why you are confused?

Comment: One of the most famous distinctions is a legal one:  Tax evasion is illegal while tax avoidance is not only legal, it's expected.

Comment: I would not use "evade" in the above pair. It seems like "evade" is used when someone sentient (e.g., a criminal) is avoiding someone else, also sentient (e.g., a police officer). If a criminal *avoided* capture, it may be through hiding or running. If a criminal *evaded* capture, he was being pursued by police. The criminal evades by altering his course. You don't evade a ball because it is not chasing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Avoid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avoid) is a transitive verb. The salient portion of the definition is definition 3:

> a :  to keep away from :  SHUN. *have been avoiding me*
>
> b :  to prevent the occurrence or effectiveness of : *avoid further delays*
>
> c :  to refrain from : *avoid overeating*

[Evade](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evade) can be transitive or intransitive.

Here are the intransitive meanings:

> 1:  to slip away
>
> 2:  to take refuge in escape or avoidance

These definitions carry the connotation of criminal activity.

Here are the transitive meanings:

> 1 :  to elude by dexterity or stratagem
>
> 2a :  to avoid facing up to " *evaded the real issues*
> 2b :  to avoid the performance of :  dodge, circumvent; especially :  to fail to pay (taxes)
> 2c :  to avoid answering directly :  turn aside
>
> 3:  to be elusive to :  baffle

The word "avoid" is used in the definition of "evade," giving a different flavor to the latter. These are not necessarily criminal, but there does seem to be some conscious strategy being applied to *evade* that is not present in *avoid*.

In your example above, it makes sense that you would *avoid* the ball (using the first definition: "to keep away from"). But it does not make so much sense to say that you *evade* the ball. You're not slipping away from or escaping the ball. The "avoidance" in intransitive definition 2 is not taking refuge in avoidance. (To be this kind of evasion, you would be perhaps fake stomach cramps to stay off the field. But the other player would not have just thrown the ball at you.) You're also not eluding *the ball*, transitive definition 1.

In short, although *evade* has *avoidance* (of something) in the definition, the words are neither synonyms nor interchangable.

Answer (score 1):

Evade can simply mean avoid.  Or it can mean escape.

If you evade pursuit then there was pursuit, you just avoided capture.

If you avoid pursuit then there never was any pursuit.  There might have been but you avoided it starting in the first place.

The problem with analyzing your sentences is that it isn't clear what's being addressed: the ball or the throwing of the ball.

You can certainly avoid the ball.  If by evade you just mean avoid then it's still correct.  If you mean evade in the sense of escape then it implies that you are doing more than dodging the ball but actually keeping it from being thrown at you.  This contradicts the first part of the sentence that left no doubt that it did get thrown at you.

So both can be correct depending on what you mean.  I'd say the first would be prefered just to avoid having to think about it this much.

Answer (score 1):

**Conclusion**

*Avoid* is ultimately from the Old French *voide,* meaning "empty" or "clear out, withdraw." If something bad happens and you've taken steps to not be there, you've avoided it.

*Evade* is from Latin *evadere* "to escape, get away," which carries a sense of having been targeted or threatened to some degree. It communicates avoidance, with the extra concept of having been personally (although not necessarily exclusively) threatened or targeted.

**Sources (Etymonline)**

> **[Avoid](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=avoid)** *(v.)* c. 1300, from Anglo-French
> avoider "to clear out, withdraw (oneself)," partially anglicized from
> Old French esvuidier "to empty out," from es- "out" (see ex-) +
> vuidier "to be empty," from voide "empty, vast, wide, hollow, waste"
> (see void (adj.)) [...]
>
> **[Evade](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=evade)** *(v.)* 1510s, "escape," from
> Middle French evader, from Latin evadere "to escape, get away," from
> assimilated form of ex- "away" (see ex-) + vadere "to go, walk" [...]